# Save/restore state of custom views in android

Tags: android, android-studio, view, android-custom-view, custom-view

I've implemented custom views for EditText as you can see in below image:

[image: Custom view for edittext]

Now this custom view includes feature of flipping, editing, rotating, drag & drop and resizing. I'm saving this custom view in bitmap format in explorer. The problem is I want to edit it and I want to restore the detail of the custom view and retrieve each and every detail of the CustomView even the position of it. So, is there any way how to implement it?

Comment: then save it so some serialization mechanizm like JSON or XML. Save it's properties in somewhere.

Comment: @VladMatvienko I want to implement it offline. So, is there any way I can do it?

Comment: Did I say something about online?

Comment: @VladMatvienko I actually wanted to save whole state which includes many views, and positions, which I think storing the value in JSON or XML is not the feasible solution here, is there any other way we can do that?

Comment: basically you need to serialize it. Most common serialization formats are JSON and XML. So in fact, there are a lot of ways. You can create even your own serialization format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, after searching for few days I got a solution for this.

There is a library named [StickerView](https://github.com/wuapnjie/StickerView) which helps to store the data of particular **Drawable Sticker** or any **Text Sticker** by using `Matrix` and many details can be stored by using The object of **`StickerView`** and can be customised by the requirements of an application.

There is one more library similar to this [StickerView](https://github.com/kencheung4/android-StickerView).

Answer (score 4):

You need to store all editing like :

`Rotation` : for this you have to maintain angle from initial value 0 to next rotation value.

`Flip` : create one flag for this , and set True , false value for front and back.

`Text` : you know how take text form `EditText`.

`Layout position within parent View`:

for calculating layout postion within parent View  use below method and create  four int variable for this ,

`Left`   =

`Top`    =

`Right`   =

`Bottom`    =

`Height` =

`Width`  =

```
private Map<String,Integer>  getPositionOnScreen(View view){
        Map<String,Integer> map = new HashMap<String,Integer>();
        View rootLayout = view.getRootView().findViewById(android.R.id.content);

        int[] viewLocation = new int[2];
        view.getLocationOnScreen(viewLocation);

        int[] rootLocation = new int[2];
        rootLayout.getLocationOnScreen(rootLocation);

        int relativeLeft = viewLocation[0] - rootLocation[0];
        int relativeTop  = viewLocation[1] - rootLocation[1];

        int height = viewLocation[0] - rootLocation[0];
        int width  = viewLocation[1] - rootLocation[1];


        map.put("left",relativeLeft);
        map.put("top",relativeTop);
        map.put("height",view.getLayoutParams().height);
        map.put("width",view.getLayoutParams().width);
        return map;
    }
```

Above method return left and top  position of view , but you need to calculate  right and bottom position from left , top and height , width .

Create one Pojo to hold all this parameters together and store this pojo into SharedPreferences or Data Base or in Application Context.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest  way of doing it

- 1 - Store all the required properties in a preference via map, Pojo
  or via serialization.
- 2 - Keep multiple keys in the case of multiple
  views.
- 3 - Once the specific screen is launched, get the view
  properties from preferences and set it on view ( right a util method 
  which take a Pref key, set everything and return the view ).